# How to reformat all the documents of a folder in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript, format, visual-studio-code, reformat

I know that I can reformat a single document by using shortcut key Alt+Shift+F (or simply right clicking on the document and clicking Format Document)

But I want to do that same for the entire project folder at once.
How can I do that?

My projects are Typescript files in Angular Framework.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that?

Use tsfmt : https://github.com/vvakame/typescript-formatter